# Airflow not loading dags in /usr/local/airflow/dags

Tags: airflow

Airflow seems to be skipping the dags I added to /usr/local/airflow/dags.

When I run

```
airflow list_dags
```

The output shows

```
[2017-08-06 17:03:47,220] {models.py:168} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags


-------------------------------------------------------------------
DAGS
-------------------------------------------------------------------
example_bash_operator
example_branch_dop_operator_v3
example_branch_operator
example_http_operator
example_passing_params_via_test_command
example_python_operator
example_short_circuit_operator
example_skip_dag
example_subdag_operator
example_subdag_operator.section-1
example_subdag_operator.section-2
example_trigger_controller_dag
example_trigger_target_dag
example_xcom
latest_only
latest_only_with_trigger
test_utils
tutorial
```

But this doesn't include the dags in /usr/local/airflow/dags

```
ls -la /usr/local/airflow/dags/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 3 airflow airflow 4096 Aug  6 17:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 airflow airflow 4096 Aug  6 16:57 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 airflow airflow 1645 Aug  6 17:03 custom_example_bash_operator.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 airflow airflow 4096 Aug  6 17:08 __pycache__
```

Is there some other condition that neededs to be satisfied for airflow to identify a DAG and load it?

Answer (score 40):

My dag is being loaded but I had the name of the DAG wrong. I was expecting the dag to be named by the file but the name is determined by the first argument to the DAG constructor

```
dag = DAG(
    'tutorial', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(1))
```

Comment: Yes, the first element is DAG id, you can see the variables list [here](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#airflow.models.DAG)

Comment: by the gods, thank you. I was running into the same issue

Comment: Thanks, I have done the same mistake, this answer helped me.

Comment: thanks for your answer, you save the rest of my afternoon!

Comment: Dear god, this just saved me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 35):

Try  **airflow db init** before listing the dags. This is because **airflow** **list_dags** lists down all the dags present in the database (And not in the folder you mentioned). Airflow initdb will create entry for these dags in the database.

Make sure you have environment variable AIRFLOW_HOME set to /usr/local/airflow. If this variable is not set, airflow looks for dags in the home airflow folder, which might not be existing in your case.

Answer (score 11):

The example files are not in /usr/local/airflow/dags. You can simply mute them by edit airflow.cfg (usually in ~/airflow). set `load_examples = False` in 'core' section.

There are couple of errors may make your DAG not been listed in `list_dags`.

1. Your DAG file has syntax issue. To check this, just run `python custom_example_bash_operator.py` and see if any issue.
2. See if the folder is the default dag loading path. For a new bird, I suggest that just create a new .py file and copy the sample from here [`https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/tutorial.html`](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/tutorial.html) then see if the testing dag shows up.
3. Make sure there is `dag = DAG('dag_name', default_args=default_args)` in the dag file.

Answer (score 7):

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_bash_operator', 
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60))
```

When a DAG is instantiated it pops up by the name you specify in the **dag_id** attribute. **dag_id** serves as a unique identifier for your DAG

Answer (score 7):

It will be the case if airflow.cfg config is pointed to an incorrect path.

**STEP 1:** Go to {basepath}/src/config/

**STEP 2:** Open `airflow.cfg` file

**STEP 3:** Check the path it should point to the dags folder you have created

```
dags_folder = /usr/local/airflow/dags
```

Answer (score 4):

I find that I have to restart the scheduler for the UI to pick up the new dags, When I make changes to a dag in my dags folder. I find that when I update the dags they appear in the list when I run **airflow list_dags** just not in the UI until I restart the scheduler.

First try running:

```
airflow scheduler
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be two issues:
1. Check the Dag name given at the time of DAG object creation in the DAG python program

```
dag = DAG(
dag_id='Name_Of_Your_DAG', 
....)
```

Note that many of the times the name given may be the same as the already present name in the list of DAGs (since if you copied the DAG code). If this is not the case then 
2. Check the path set to the DAG folder in Airflow's config file.
You can create DAG file anywhere on your system but you need to set the path to that DAG folder/directory in Airflow's config file.

For example, I have created my DAG folder in the Home directory then I have to edit airflow.cfg file using the following commands in the terminal:

creating a DAG folder at home or root directory

```
$mkdir ~/DAG
```

Editing airflow.cfg present in the airflow directory where I have installed the airflow

```
 ~/$cd airflow
 ~/airflow$nano airflow.cfg
```

In this file change dags_folder path to DAG folder that we have created.

If you still facing the problem then reinstall the Airflow and refer this [link](https://limitlessdatascience.wordpress.com/2019/10/01/apache-airflow-installation-steps/) for the installation of Apache Airflow.

Comment: This helped me! I had copied a DAG to a new file and forgot to change the id.

Answer (score 1):

Are your

```
custom_example_bash_operator.py
```

has a DAG name different from the others? 
If yes, try restart the scheduler or even resetdb. I usually mistook the filename to be the dag name as well, so better to name them the same.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share what is in `custom_example_bash_operator.py`? Airflow scans for certain magic inside a file to determine whether is a DAG or not. It scans for `airflow` and for `DAG`.

In addition if you are using a duplicate dag_id for a DAG it will be overwritten. As you seem to be deriving from the example bash operator did you keep the name of the DAG `example_bash_operator` maybe? Try renaming that.

Comment: This is what got me. I thought it would scan for `DAG` objects, but it literally first scans the file for the strings `DAG` and `airflow` before even attempting to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set airflow first and initialise the db

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/myfolder
mkdir /myfolder/dags
airflow db init
```

You need to create a user too

```
 airflow users create \
          --username admin \
          --firstname FIRST_NAME \
          --lastname LAST_NAME \
          --role Admin \
          --email admin@example.org
```

If you have done it correctly you should see `airflow.cfg` in your folder. There you will find `dags_folder` which shows the dags folder.

If you have saved your dag inside this folder you should see it in the dag lists

```
airflow dags list
```

, or using the UI with

```
airflow webserver --port 8080
```

Otherwise, run again `airflow db init`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `print(something)` in dag file prevented printing dag list on command line.

Check if there is print line in your dag if above solutions are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had issue in loading the dynamic DAG alone and found that in Airflow version 2.4.2, if you modify the attributes like on_*_callback for dynamic DAG then it resulted in error to occur. Please check this Github issues for more details.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/30012

This is fixed in 2.5.1 Airflow version

Answer (score 0):

Following points should resolve the issue of sample dag vs main dags.

1. edit airflow.cfg set load_examples = False.
2. Verify if the dags_folder points to your dags folder.
3. restart Webserver and Scheduler.

Note: dag_dir_list_interval in airflow.cfg decides, How often (in seconds) to scan the DAGs directory for new files. So that your newly added dags appear in the 'DAGS' list on the UI.

Answer (score -9):

Try Restarting the scheduler. Scheduler needs to be restarted when new DAGS need to be added to the DAG Bag

Comment: This is not true. The scheduler picks up new dags in the dag bag.

Comment: Adding to the above, the scheduler runs at regular intervals. But if u want to see your newly added dag in your dagbag instantly, then restarting would be something to go with or reduce the time between each scan by scheduler.